# Switching pages instead of windows

Tags: c#

So currently I'm switching to a whole new window when i use my page switch button. But what I actually would like it to do is in the same window switch to another page. I have searched the internet and found some page switch with a button but when I set it up and click the button half the screen just goes white and the other half stays. I hope someone can help me with some click event or something that can do what I need. Hope you understand what I mean.

My current code for switching windows on a button click is this:

```
            Newpage objNewpage = new Newpage();
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            objNewpage.Show();
```

Put instead what I would like is to open a new page on the same window.

//Ossie

Comment: Post your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then it would be answered faster. Also including what you want to achieve.

Comment: It might be just me, but I have no idea what this question is about, what domain the question is asked in, what technology or framework. What is a page?

Comment: Im sorry I'm really new to C#. So I'm working in WPF and I want to achieve a switch between pages in the same window. I have put in the code in the original question. @TheGeneral

Comment: @OskarStefanski To you want to use a `TabControl` to switch around the content?